# typesscript declar module with regex

Tags: typescript, declare

Is there a way to declare multiple modules at once in typescript?

For example, how can I simplify this code:

```js
declare module '*.png' {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}

declare module '*.jpg' {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}

declare module '*.gif' {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}

declare module '*.svg' {
    const value: any;
    export = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a regular expression or a glob as the name of a module. However, if all these image files are in a single folder, such as `images/`, then you can do the following:

```
declare module 'images/*' {
  const value: any;
  export = value;
}
```